# Can I start angular project from body level or it should only start from HTML only?

Tags: angularjs-scope

I am starting with angular project so my doubt is Can I start angular project from body level or it should only start from HTML only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your angular app from any level of the DOM! I.e. you can put ng-app at body or at any of the div in the body.
The only concern is angular app will be available to that scope only. Hope this will help.